# How to use inverted hull method for anime outlines?

Tags: shaders, toon-shading

I am trying to create anime stylized components for the Unity game engine.
Almost every tutorial I find mentions the inverted hull method and describe it like this:

- Make outline material with black coloured emission node
- Turn on backface culling
- Put a Solidify modifier on object
- On solidify, flip normals, material index on 1 (or whatever the outline index position is), change thickness

And you are done, end of tutorial.

However, when I try this I get very ugly and crazy lines/artifecats.
[image: Component without lines][image: Component with lines]

I can't figure out for the life of me what to do with this, no tutorial I have found goes beyond just explaining the steps I just mentioned to fix these artifacts.

Could someone explain how to fix these artifacts or point me in the direction where I can find the solution?

Comment: The technique is appropriate for manifold, smooth-shaded meshes without self-intersection.  It is not appropriate for other kinds of meshes, like the one you are showing.

Answer (score 0):

was just looking for the same thing. Basically you go into the material settings for the outline and change the shadow mode from opaque to none. Here is a link to the video that explains alot. Hope this fixes the problem :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hp4V-9oFmnM
(4.50 he explains about this bug)